# How to fix this code for a Java program that simulates a simple calculator?

Tags: java

Kindly help me to fix this code for a Java program that simulates a simple calculator.

It reads two integers and a character. If the character is a +, the sum is printed; if it is a -, the difference is printed; if it is a *, the product is printed; if it is a /, the quotient is printed; and if it is a %, the remainder is printed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class calc {
    private int a,b,and;
    private char c;
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println ("Enter the first Integer");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        a=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second Integer");
        b=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the operation sign");
        c=scan.nextChar();
        if (c=='+')
            and=a+b;
        else if (c=='-')
            and=a-b;
        else if (c=='*')
            and=a*b;
        else if (c=='/')
            and=a/b;
        else if (c=='%')
            and=a%b;
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong operation");
        exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("The result is "+ ans);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is riddled with spelling errors. At least check your code before you post it here.

Comment: spelling mistake   c=scna.nextChar(); Also why not you are using Switch case to avoid so many 'if else'

Comment: i do not know how to use "Switch", this is my first java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Make all your variables static so that you can use them within main or i would suggest move them within main.
2. Use nextLine().charAt(0) instead of nextChar which isn't defined in Scanner.
3. Instead of `newxInt();` use `nextInt(); api of Scanner`
4. out is a static field (note lower case o), so change System.Out to System.out.
5. do an `import static java.lang.System.exit;` so you could use `exit(0);` without any issues from compiler.

Edit: Just for OP (Make sure you give meaningful name to variables) -

```
import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calc {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a, b, ans = 0;
        char c;
        System.out.println("Enter the first Integer");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the second Integer");
        b = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the operation sign");
        c = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
        if (c == '+')
            ans = a + b;
        else if (c == '-')
            ans = a - b;
        else if (c == '*')
            ans = a * b;
        else if (c == '/')
            ans = a / b;
        else if (c == '%')
            ans = a % b;
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong operation");
            exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("The result is " + ans);
    }
}

Output:
Enter the first Integer
10
Enter the second Integer
20
Enter the operation sign
+
The result is 30
```

Comment: Can you please write the complete right code, I changed point No.4 but I am afraid to mess thing up if I edit more , kindly write the complete right code so I can compare and learn form my mistakes

Comment: See my edited answer. Dont just copy paste it. Just have a look at it and modify it accordingly. Make sure you use appropriate variables names and follow camel case and coding conventions.

Comment: I can learn now from my mistakes because of you make it so obvious what I did wrong , you are the best, thank you very much . I will make sure of variables and case and conventions

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
c=scna.nextChar();
```

to

```
c=scan.nextChar();
```

Also change

`exit(0)`

to

`System.exit(0)`

`b=scan.newxInt();` to `b=scan.nextInt();`

Change all `Out` to `out`

Comment: Yeah I'm getting on it :D

Comment: I admire your effort, but posting code that is so far from runnable is an insult to the people trying to assist here on SO.

Comment: I literally need to kill time before I go in a few minutes lol so I kinda dc